# gdx-freetype is slow to generate fonts

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm currently using the gdx-freetype library to generate the BitmapFonts for my game. It's really convenient since I can use it to handle the different screen sizes on Android. The problem is that it takes a long time for a font to be made. At startup I generate some BitmapFonts in a few different sizes (from the same .ttf file), so the time spent generating fonts, adds to my loading time. This is a problem, since it can easily take 5-6 seconds to generate the fonts.

Is there anything I can do to speed up the process or should I try some alternative to gdx-freetype? Perhaps I'm approaching this problem in a wrong way?

Comment: Profile your code and first test it is the FreeType code, then, if it is, what its bottleneck is.

Comment: I'm sure it's FreeType. It occurs on the actual generation of the BitmapFont, which in my case is this line: `generator.generateFont(parameter)`. I'm not sure, but I don't think the hang is because of a bug, those few seconds might just be the time it takes for FreeType to generate the font.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the long loading times are only on mobile devices. My PC gets much better results, as you would expect from a much better CPU.

Comment: Save the generated fonts as files the first time the game loads, and then load the files directly in subsequent game loads.

Comment: How to save them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tenfour04 correctly points out in the comments, the way to do this is to only generate the fonts once when the game first loads, then save them as files. Subsequent runs will simply load them from the files which will be much faster.

I've heard good things about the [gdx-smart-font](https://github.com/jrenner/gdx-smart-font) project which does exactly this, although I should add that I've never actually tried it myself...

> This class provides several benefits:
>
> Creating fonts for different screen sizes using Hiero or BMFont can be
>   troublesome, if you have 4 fonts of different sizes and are targeting
>   5-6 different screen sizes, you then must generate 20-24 bitmap font
>   pngs. By using generated fonts they can be dynamically scaled at the
>   time of creation based on screen size.
>
> Generating fonts cuts down on app download size, no need to include
>   pngs.
>
> Generating fonts can add significant time to app startup time. Caching
>   the generated fonts to file, and only regenerating when needed allows
>   for fast app startup most of the time.